What is the right way to separate the text in the equation?
For example, I have the following tex code.
    \begin{equation}
    (\rho,\rho u)(0,x)=(\rho_0,m_0)(x)\to(\rho_{\pm},m_{\pm}) \text{as} x\to \pm\infty\label{InitialData}
\end{equation}

the word “as” and the equation $x\to$ are stuck together.

So what is the right way to insert a blank between the equation and the text?

\text{ as } is easy to remember

Welcome to TeX.SX! If needed, larger spaces can be obtained with the usual \quad or \qquad commands.
